# How to to open MSTeams to send a message to a user (chat) from a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, microsoft-teams

```
private void ContactDataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2) // Assuming it's the first column
    {
        Process.Start("mailto:" + 
            ContactDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

This is my code to add an email hyperlink to my datagridview. The email is taken from a textbox. I would like to do the same where I would enter a contact into a textbox and can then click this hyperlink to open up Microsoft Teams along with the contact.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `msteams:` url scheme like this:

```
Process.Start("msteams:l/chat/0/0?users=user@example.com&message=Hello")
```

Then it opens Microsoft Teams with a draft message ready to send to the user.

You can find the documentations here:

- [Deep link to start a new chat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-workflow?tabs=teamsjs-v2&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#deep-link-to-start-a-new-chat)

I just replaced the web URL with `msteam:` url scheme.

Comment: Note: The user must exists in the directory, otherwise it just opens the MS Team, without drafting a message.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you to use [GraphAPI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) for Microsoft teams so you manipulate your application with Microsoft Teams chats, channels and connections and many else

Best