# Start Teams call from WinForms application - c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to start a Microsoft Teams call from my WinForms c# application.

I think this is possible by opening a link that then triggers the Teams app to open.
I've searched the internet and stack overflow but can't find any good working examples.

I've also tried the below code, but nothing opens.

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<username>");
```

Changed ProcessStart code to the below and it will now open the link, but I receive an error within the Teams app: 'There's a problem with the link'

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>") { UseShellExecute = true });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `msteams:` url scheme like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msteams:l/call/0/0?users=user@example.com");
```

Then it opens Microsoft Teams and asks you if you want to make the call.
You can find the supported format and parameters of here:

- [Deep link to start an audio-video call with users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-link-workflow?tabs=teamsjs-v2&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#deep-link-to-start-an-audio-video-call-with-users)

I just replaced the web URL with `msteam:` url scheme.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.
Do you know how I would make a phone call to a mobile phone number?

Comment: ?users=user@example.com,4:+9876543210

Comment: Hmm, that one didn't work but I should be able to figure it out from here. Is there any documentation for these teams link commands?

Comment: I've added the documentation link to the answer. This is the format that is expected to work. For me it shows you are not allowed to setup a phone call through MSTeams, but I guess it means it works.

Comment: And here is my answer about chat: [How to to open MSTeams to send a message to a user (chat) from a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72737407/3110834); you may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is your link is not correct.
Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70390534/20466471).
[Start Teams call from c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375470/start-teams-call-from-c-sharp)

And also try this kind of link for voice call:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>
```

and try this kind for video call:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>&withVideo=true
```

Comment: Okay so it looks like it was a problem with my Process code. I have now changed the code to Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/call/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>") { UseShellExecute = true });

And it will open the link and Teams but I am receiving the error: "There's a problem with the link"